# Visual Composer - Hide/Show on Desktop and Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm trying to hide and show a column when it's on desktop or on mobile.
I've been trying for few hours to make it work but to no avail. As you can see in the images attached, the one circled in red is what I'm trying to hide.

I tried to put in extra class named hide_mobile for the one I but it didn't work:

```
              @media only screen and (max-width: 674px)  {
             .hide_mobile{
              display:none !important;
              }
              }
```

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV5nh.png)

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sp5s.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the html code for that column?  It's hard to tell just from the css you posted if you are targeting the correct column or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress you can do a stylesheet only for mobile.
For example mobile.css and with a php code in the header, you can call it only when you are using a mobile phone.This is an example for mobile and ipad:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 80px) and (max-width: 700px)"     href="/wp-content/themes/theme-child/iphone.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)'     href='/wp-content/themes/theme-child/ipad.css'>
```

With me it works great.